# Probability that a fair coin will land all the same in $3$ consecutive tosses

Tags: probability, statistics

Why is the probability that a fair coin will land the same (all heads or all tails) on $3$ consecutive tosses not $\frac{1}{8}$? Is it not $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because there are two ways it can happen: all heads, all tails, and 1/8+1/8=1/4.

Comment: Oh wow.... I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

`TTT` $\; \Large\leftarrow$
`TTH`
`THT`
`THH`
`HTT`
`HTH`
`HHT`
`HHH` $\;\Large\leftarrow$

Sample space size: $8$

"Probability of all heads $\bf OR$ all tails":
$\quad P(TTT) + P(HHH) = \dfrac 18 + \dfrac 18 = \dfrac 14$

Comment: Nice formatting and I'd lose if I had to get either of the endpoints! :-) +1